# Should I get link status on a direct connection between two switches?

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, switch

I'm creating a sort of daisy-chain network between two switches, the current layout is as follows:

Router -> Switch 1 -> Switch 2

Currently, there is not link status (green light) between any of the devices. My question is: should I get link status between either the Router and Switch 1, or Switch 1 and Switch 2, if there are no other devices attached to this network.

Comment: The short answer is yes, you **should** get layer 2 connectivity between the devices just by connecting them.  If they are older devices, it might be necessary to use crossover cables.  That's the first thing I would try.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/1275649/750903. C’mon now, your cables haven’t been made properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I hadn't actually crimped the jacks, assuming I could 'commit' to my cabling after testing the cable. Please see [this answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/42697/8499) for a more detailed description of what to do when your custom cables aren't working.

As for this question, the answer is yes, two network switches with a working ethernet cable between them should get link status (flashing lights).

Answer (score 1):

Are these Gigabit switches?  Crossovers aren't required with gigabit.

Some older switches have a button next to the first or last port; use that port, and toggle the button on one of the switches.

Store-bought, or home-made cables?  If the latter, ensure both ends have been wired to the same T-568B or T-568A conventional pinouts, and the cable is of sufficient category and not over the specified length for the line speed.[image: Standard Wiring pinouts for Ethernet]