# Can I test my custom CAT5e cable before crimping?

Tags: networking, ethernet, home-networking, cable, cat5e

I am wiring up my home using CAT5e cable. Before committing to the cables I have created, I have plugged them in (uncrimped) and they are not working.

Do I need to take the plunge and crimp the cables before I can test them? I was hoping to wire up first and buy a crimping tool later this week. Apologies if this is an obvious question, I couldn't seem to find this information anywhere.

Comment: The cables are not working because you need to finish making them.

Comment: I upvoted this. It might be obvious to some, but just because it's not possible doesn't make asking if it is, in itself a bad question.

Comment: I ***highly*** recommend getting a cheap [ethernet tester](https://www.amazon.com/HDE-Network-Cable-Tester-Phone/dp/B009ZXYI1U/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1512917660&sr=8-6&keywords=ethernet+tester) with a remote end.  This tool will save you hours of frustration.

Answer (score 3):

Crimping makes the actual connection by cutting through the insulation on the wires. The colored plastic is insulation; the copper *conductor* is inside that. There are V-shaped notches on the terminal for each wire that cut precisely through the insulation and compress the wires inside.

Though it is possible to reach the conductor using a needle-tip probe, it certainly would not be worth the time or trouble to do so. The cable itself is reliable, but [applying the RJ-45 crimping tool correctly is critical](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-YCFIhGhHs).

Comment: As an addendum to this answer - I'd highly recommend making up a few small disposable cables first, to practise the method. It's not as easy as it looks when you first start, & as has been pointed out, you can't really test them until they're finished.

Comment: @Tetsujin has a good point: press *too hard* and the conductors may be cut, but pressing *too gently* may not cut through insulation.